Is the universe logical?
And if it is, can there be anything that is illogical, if we start from a logical world?
I don't know much about philosophy, and this question is bugging me a little. Please be understanding! Thank you!

Logic is the study of correct reasoning. In what sense the universe "is logical"? The universe does not reason nor deduce.

Thanks Mauro. I can't really answer "in what sense" it would be logical as I was asking if it was, and I wouldn't really know. That does clear things up a bit, that the universe can't reason or deduce.

The universe appears to follow logical principles, at least in the sense that we can describe its behavior with laws of physics and consistent patterns. But the question of whether the universe itself is "logical" is a bit more complex. Logic is a framework we use to interpret and predict; it’s a tool our minds created to make sense of things. So, it’s possible the universe seems logical because we’re interpreting it through a logical framework.
If we start with the assumption that the universe is entirely logical, then, in theory, nothing genuinely illogical could emerge from it. But this doesn’t mean everything would be easily understandable. There could be phenomena that seem illogical simply because we lack the knowledge or perspective to understand them. So, we may sometimes encounter things that appear illogical, but this could be due to limitations in our understanding rather than a flaw in the universe itself.

"The universe appears to follow logical principles..." Humans are part of the universe? "... nothing genuinely illogical could emerge from it." What about wars?

If the universe is deterministic, then even actions like war are logical results of a chain of causes and consequences. The logic of nature doesn’t follow the same rules as our human sense of right and wrong.

Yes, righta and wrong are human, but also logic is, because logic is language and dialogue. The (physical) universe does not speak nor deduce.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I think OP and Yann are referencing some kind of physical or metaphysical necessity/order, not that the universe is a system that is run in formal logic. That there are fundamental principles of being/nature, like the law of non-contradiction, go back to antiquity seems to corroborate the meaning of ‘logical’ present in the question. The law of non-contradiction is a metaphysical claim according to Aristotle, after all.


Logic in its broadest sense is the set of rules of our thinking. The
universe does not think. Hence it is not meaningful to ask whether
the universe is logical or illogical.
Except under the premise that
the universe is mind-like, which is a rather problematic assumption.

But in any case, it is an interesting question why we do find out
results about the universe by applying logical thinking to our
observations.
Some persons speculate that the universe is a computer
simulation.
But the question is totally open.


